# system() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I have the following Python code running on Python version 2.7 and Windows.

The code basically grabs the URL from my active Google Chrome tab, then runs and passes the URL as an argument to a Windows batch file.

```
import os
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

omniboxHwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, 'Chrome_OmniboxView', None)

def getWindowText(hwnd):
    buf_size = 1 + win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
    buf = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(buf_size)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, buf_size, buf)
    return str(buf)

url = getWindowText(hwnd)

exe = 'run.bat "%s"' %(url)

os.system(exe)
```

However, running the code from the command line throws the following error:

```
TypeError: system() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str
```

Is there something that I'm missing out here?

EDIT: Manually inputting a URL string works, i.e. replacing

```
url = getWindowText(hwnd)
```

with

```
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976936/"
```

works, so it seems that the problem lies with how the code grabs the URL string from the window. I took the code from [How do I get the URL of the active Google Chrome tab in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645123/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-active-google-chrome-tab-in-windows) and I'm not familiar with it at all. Is there an alternative way to grab the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265084/typeerror-must-be-string-without-null-bytes-not-str)

Comment: I've tried adding r before my exe string, but the error still pops up.

Comment: The problem is not the string literal `'run.bat "%s"'` but `url`, which probably contains the null-byte.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but how should I edit url? Stripping url doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try `url.strip('\x00')`. This on the other hand will not help, if the null-byte is somewhere in the middle. Simple `str.strip()` call will remove whitespace, which a null-byte is not.

Comment: **GetWindowText function** 
*Copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied.* **However, `GetWindowText` cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application**. And further *To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling `GetWindowText`*

Comment: To remove null bytes you can always do `url.replace('\x00', '')`. But this only hides the issue. You should *not* have null bytes in the first place. There's probably something bogus with the logic used to create the buffer/string.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, it seems like it didn't work.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I got it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645123/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-active-google-chrome-tab-in-windows. The `replace` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You should also include the full traceback, not just the final error in your post. May not be useful in this particular case, but it's a good habit.

Comment: (I would like to retract duplicate flag but I can't.)